# MYSQL Query Multiple Condition and SUM function

Tags: mysql

Well, I have these columns in my table:

1. wo_number
2. crew_est
3. manhour_est
4. status ('FINISH' or NULL)
5. progress (this isn't in the table)

I need to do this calculation for progress:

```
progress = SUM(crew_est * manhour_est) WHERE status = 'FINISH') / (SUM(crew_est * manhour_est) WHERE status IS NULL);
```

I need to do the calculation above and group the result by wo_number. I've looking for the answer anywhere but still no luck and I've no idea where to start.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: So, the progress will be per wo_number?

Comment: @GurwinderSingh yes, correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use case for conditional aggregation:

```
select wo_Number,
    100.0 * SUM(case 
            when status = 'FINISH'
                then crew_est * manhour_est
            else 0
            end) / SUM(case 
            when status is null
                then crew_est * manhour_est
            else 0
            end) progress_percentage
from your_table
group by wo_number;
```

Comment: I forgot to add, how do I retrieve the progress result in percentage? thanks in advance, your query is working.

Comment: @MAnsyori Is the percentage not just multiplied by 100?

Comment: Correct, just multiplied the percentage by 100. Thank you so much.